# R Merge Two Dataframes on columns keep columns

Tags: r, join, dataframe, merge, concatenation

Apologies, if this is a duplicate please let me know, I'll gladly delete.

I am merging two datasets in R using `merge`.

```
age1 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11) 
fname1 = c('david','alan','ben', 'ben', 'richard', 'edd') 
sname1 = c('albert','raymond','albert','pete','raymond', 'alan')
area1 = c('r','t','n','x','z','w')

df1 <- data.frame(age1, fname1, sname1, area1)

age2 = c(5, 9, 10, 3, 4, 0) 
fname2 = c('david','alan','david', 'ben', 'richard', 'edd') 
sname2 = c('albert','edd','albert','pete','raymond', 'alan')
area2 = c('w','z','x','n','t','r')

df2 = data.frame(age2, fname2, sname2, area2)
```

Dataset1:

```
df1
  age1  fname1  sname1 area1
1    5   david  albert     r
2    6    alan raymond     t
3    7     ben  albert     n
4    8     ben    pete     x
5   10 richard raymond     z
6   11     edd    alan     w
```

Dataset 2

```
df2
  age2  fname2  sname2 area2
1    5   david  albert     w
2    9    alan     edd     z
3   10   david  albert     x
4    3     ben    pete     n
5    4 richard raymond     t
6    0     edd    alan     r
```

I merge on `fname` and `sname` with:

```
matchkey <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("fname1", "sname1"), by.y = c("fname2", "sname2"))
View(matchkey)
```

Output:

```
> matchkey
   fname1  sname1 age1 area1 age2 area2
1     ben    pete    8     x    3     n
2   david  albert    5     r    5     w
3   david  albert    5     r   10     x
4     edd    alan   11     w    0     r
5 richard raymond   10     z    4     t
```

However, I want to *keep* the columns I have merged on. How can I do this? Should I use something other than merge?

Expected Output:

```
   fname1  sname1 age1 area1  fname2   sname 2age2  area2
1     ben    pete    8     x  ben    pete      3       n
2   david  albert    5     r  david  albert    5       w
3   david  albert    5     r  david  albert    10      x
4     edd    alan   11     w  edd    alan      0       r
5 richard raymond   10     z  richard raymond  4       t
```

I tried looking at, but to no success:

[How do I combine two data-frames based on two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709151/how-do-i-combine-two-data-frames-based-on-two-columns)

[Combining two dataframes keeping all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025026/combining-two-dataframes-keeping-all-columns)

[Merge two dataframes with repeated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374459/merge-two-dataframes-with-repeated-columns)

Many thanks.

Comment: It would be easy enough to tack these columns on afterwards. like `matchkey[c("fname2", "sname2")] <- matchkey[c("fname1", "sname1")]`, though it seems redundant to me.

Comment: Aren't the columns you want to add by definition exactly the same as fname1 and sname1? A quick solution is to just do: `matchkey$fname2 <- matchkey$fname1` and `matchkey$sname2 <- matchkey$sname1`

Comment: Cheers to you both. I was way overthinking this. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since merged columns would be exact same on an *inner join* or complete match between dataframes, simply assign new columns to the columns that remained. And you can do so with `transform()`. Below adds an `outer()` combination with `paste0` to retrieve needed column order:

```
matchkey <- transform(merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("fname1", "sname1"), 
                                      by.y = c("fname2", "sname2")),
                      fname2 = fname1, sname2 = sname1)

ordercols <- c(outer(c("fname", "sname", "age", "area"), c(1:2), paste0))
matchkey <- matchkey[ordercols]

matchkey    
#    fname1  sname1 age1 area1  fname2  sname2 age2 area2
# 1     ben    pete    8     x     ben    pete    3     n
# 2   david  albert    5     r   david  albert    5     w
# 3   david  albert    5     r   david  albert   10     x
# 4     edd    alan   11     w     edd    alan    0     r
# 5 richard raymond   10     z richard raymond    4     t
```

Comment: Cheers @Parfait. Nice way to do it and can be scaled to my larger dataset. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Glad to help.